# N (even) sided Polygon within Circle, with 1 given chord length, all other sides are equal

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, polygons

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6mE1.png)

Hello,

Right figure (ignore left)

I am having an issue solving this equation for even sided polygons (odd is easy as working out radius is easy)

I have a horizontal line (say 2100mm) (a1 from right image),

and a perpendicular measurement from the large horizontal line to the parallel/opposite side of the polygon (say 500mm) (ai from right image).

E.g.

6 sided polygon (need equation to be n dependent)

length n1 = 2100.
length n2 = n3 = n4 = n5 = n6

Arc of n1n2 = n6n1

arc of n2n3 = n3n4 = n4n5 = n5n6

all intersecting point are on circumference of a circle.

How do I work out length n2,n3,n4,n5,n6

and arcs n2n3,n3n4,n4n5,n5n6 OR n1n2,n6n1

with constraints n1 = 2100, n1 & n4 are parallel and perpendicular distance = 500.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you mark what exactly $500$ is supposed to be in the diagram?

Comment: a1 is horizontal (2100), ai is also horizontal (500) and n4 in this case, i.e. 2 faucets either side connecting them. ai is also perfectly centralized on the horizontal plane to a1

Comment: Sorry if Im not explaining this the best.

Comment: Presumably, $a_i$ is wrong in the left figure.

Comment: Please ignore left figure, right figure (closest image I could find to illustrate my problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of a chord corresponding to the aperture angle $2\alpha$ is $r\cos\alpha$. So with your data, and denoting $m:=n-1$,

$$\begin{cases}a_1=r\cos(m\alpha),\\a_i=r\cos(\alpha).\end{cases}$$

So you have to solve the trigonometric equation

$$a_i\cos(m\alpha)=a_1\cos(\alpha)$$ also written

$$a_iT_m(\cos(\alpha))=a_1\cos(\alpha)$$ where $T_m$ is a Chebyshev polynomial.

Unfortunately, the equation is polynomial and for $n>4$ you can't spare a numerical resolution.

---

If you don't know $a_i$ but the distance between $a_1$ and $a_i$, the resolution will be similar, with a more complicated equation.

Comment: Thank you very much, would you be able to give the equation for when I only know the distance between a1 and ai?